# Rational canonical forms of a matrix

Tags: diagonalization

Let $A$ a $4\times 4$ matrix over the reals with $A^3-A^2+A=0$
That means that its minimal polynomial is:
$x$ or $x^2-x+1$ or $x^3-x^2+x$
In the first case $A=0$. The second case is 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}?
$$
And for the last one 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}?
$$

For the 2nd case: Since $m(x)=x^2-x+1$ and the characteristic polynomial has degree 4, the only possibility is $\chi(x)=(x^2-x+1)^2$ and from the rational canonical form I found the matrix as above, up to similarity. For the 3rd case: Since complex roots come in pairs the characteristic polynomial is $\chi (x)=x^2(x^2-x+1)$ and again using the rational canonical form I found the matrix I wrote.

Comment: Why do you think those are *the only* possibilities for $\;A\;$ (second and third cases. The first one's trivially true)?

Comment: @Timbuc Since its a $4\times 4$ real matrix. There are more cases?

Comment: but then again: how did you get those examples of matrices? And yes: there infinite examples of $\;4\times 4\;$ matrices with those minimal polynomials: just choose one of them and the conjugate it by *any* regular matrix.

Comment: @Timbuc The matrices that I wrote are up to similarity.